# How to extract the file jre-9/lib/modules?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, jdk-tools, jmod

In `JRE-9/lib` directory (at least on Windows), there is a new file called `modules` whose size is about 107 MB. Is it possible to extract that file or maybe list java modules within it?

I can see that a new tool called `jmod` is available at `jdk-9/bin/jmod.exe`, but that is for reading `.jmod` files which is located at `jdk-9/jmods` and it cannot read the file `modules`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `modules` file is a container file. It's internal to the JDK and the format is not documented (it may change at any time). For troubleshooting purposes, the `jimage` tool in the bin directory can be used to list or extract the contents.

Comment: any links to `jimage` and how it can be used would be useful as well.

Comment: There isn't a docs page for jimage but `jimage --help` should have enough. Note that the tool is included for troubleshooting/support usages, it's not something that most developers will ever need.

Comment: Worked for me. Just did `$ jimage extract $JAVA_HOME/lib/modules` and poof!

Answer (score 22):

The runtime resources are handled in a backwards compatible way. E.g. when you did

```
URL url = Object.class.getResource("Object.class");
System.out.println(url);
```

in the past, you usually got something like

```
jar:file:/path-to-jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/Object.class
```

Running the same under Java 9 will give you

```
jrt:/java.base/java/lang/Object.class
```

instead. In either case, you can open a `FileSystem` on it to inspect the other available resources (since Java 7). While the `ZipFileSystem` had to be created via `FileSystems.newFileSystem` first, Java 9’s file system is even already open for use:

```
private static void readMyOwnJRE() throws IOException {
    try {
        Path p = Paths.get(URI.create("jrt:/")).resolve("/modules");
        System.out.println("My own JRE's modules:");
        Files.list(p).forEach(m -> System.out.println(m.getFileName()));
        System.out.println();
    } catch(FileSystemNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not read my modules (perhaps not Java 9?).");
    }
}
```

If you are running under a different JRE than the one you want to inspect, you have to load the appropriate file system implementation manually first, but this opens the possibility to inspect a Java 9 installation even from a Java 8 JRE:

```
public static void readOtherJRE(Path pathToJRE) throws IOException {
    Path p = pathToJRE.resolve("lib").resolve("jrt-fs.jar");
    if(Files.exists(p)) {
        try(URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{ p.toUri().toURL() });
            FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jrt:/"),
                                                      Collections.emptyMap(),
                                                      loader)) {
            System.out.println("Modules of "+pathToJRE);
            Files.list(fs.getPath("/modules")).forEach(System.out::println);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Once you have a file system (or a `Path` into it), you can use all standard functions of, e.g. [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/nio/file/Files.html) to inspect or extract/copy the data, though the right term would be “to store an equivalent class file” in a different file system, as the runtime image’s representation doesn’t have to be a class file at all.

Comment: This solution is working great to read the content of a Java installation, however, it looks like it is leaking memory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68083239/how-to-free-all-resources-after-reading-a-jrt

Answer (score 7):

The `modules` file is meant to be a single file (not meant to be extracted anywhere) which contains a binary representation of all of the modules present in the JDK in an undocument format which is subject to change.  You can list the modules it contains with `java --list-modules`.

Initially the `modules` file will contain every module and basically double the side of the JDK on its own, but once you "minify" your JDK using the `jlink` utility, the `modules` file will become smaller (assuming your program contains a subset of the modules provided with the JDK).  For more info on `jlink` see here: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282

Comment: Why wouldn't a JDK come minified already if the developers intended it to be minified?

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
$ jimage list $JAVA_HOME/lib/modules
```

to list all the system packages' name,like "java/io/EOFException.class",etc.

also,you can use

```
$ jimage extract --dir=<directory>  $JAVA_HOME/lib/modules
```

to extract all the .class files into the specified directory.

reference:https://adoptopenjdk.gitbooks.io/adoptopenjdk-getting-started-kit/en/intermediate-steps/openjdk9-jimage.html

Answer (score 3):

You can list modules via `java --list-modules`

Answer (score 0):

You can use libjimage to read this file.