# How to get files for classes from JDK modules with Java 9+?

Tags: java, java-11

I am trying to read classes from `java.base` as `InputStream`s. I already have a method to read classfiles given a `File` object, but I am unable to obtain `File` objects, since I'm using JDK 11 and there isn't an `rt.jar` file anymore. After following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46451977) answer, I have roughly the following code (I'm using Scala, but this is essentially a question about Java, hence the tags):

```scala
val fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jrt:/"), Collections.emptyMap, loader)

Files.list(fs.getPath("/modules")).forEach { mdl =>
  Files.walk(mdl).forEach { (classFile: Path) =>
    val asFile = classFile.toAbsolutePath.toFile //Here's where I get an exception
    //do stuff with that
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I use `classFile.toFile` or `classFile.toAbsolutePath.toFile`, I get an `UnsupportedOperationException`, which I guess is because it's not a physical file. However, I require a `File` object to turn into an `InputStream` and read. How can I get `File` objects for every classfile in a certain module (or every module) that is part of the JDK?

Comment: Side note: when you’re reading your own JRE’s module storage, you don’t need to open the filesystem. Further, there’s no need to do a `list` before `walk`. Just `Files.walk(Paths.get(URI.create("jrt:/"))).forEach(…)` is enough to iterate over the entire JRE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a `File` to create an `InputStream`. You can also use a `Path` together with [`Files::newInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) :

```
Files.list(fs.getPath("/modules")).forEach(mdl -> {
  try(Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(mdl)) {
    stream.forEach(classFile -> {
      try (InputStream input = Files.newInputStream(classFile)) {
        ...
      } catch(IOException e) {
        ...
      }
    });
  } catch(IOException e) {
    ...
  }
});
```